# how to add <hr /> after each group in a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have list of object that's populated from database
and I have foreign key separate groups depending on this key
now I need to insert `<hr />` element after the end of all group
To clarify Let us take an example :

First: this is my object with foreign key

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int Emp_ID { get; set; }
    public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
    public string Emp_Email { get; set; }
    public string Emp_Tel { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> department_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Second: populating this object from data base and grouping it
using foreign key (department_ID)
... but this approach not good because it's not ordered group

```
Employee.Where(element => element.department_ID != null)
        .GroupBy(element => element.department_ID)
        .Last().ToList()
        .ForEach(s => s.Emp_Name = s.Emp_Name + "<hr />");
```

Third: I need the result to be like the following

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------
 Emp_ID  |Emp_Name  |Emp_Email  |Emp_Tel  |department_ID  
 1       |Mohamed   |Mohamed@   |123      |1
 2       |Ali       |Ali@       |123      |1
 --------------------------------------------------------<hr />
 3       |Khaled    |Khaled@    |123      |2
 4       |Ahmed     |Ahmed@     |123      |2
 --------------------------------------------------------<hr />
 5       |Suleiman  |Suleiman@  |123      |3
 6       |Eslam     |Eslam@     |123      |3
```

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't try to add markup from the query, if that's what you're saying.

Some might disagree, but I'd actually do it in the view. I'd simply loop through the data and, whenever the `department_ID` changed, I'd output an `<hr>`.

Comment: actually I need that not just to add markup but to insert element also and another several thoughts